# how to fix uncomplete html load due to large image retriverd from database blob

Tags: php, html

I have a strange problem, I am using images stored in MySQL in medium blob form, sometimes when the image is larger than 40 Kb the HTML code of the page doesn't load completely, it stops in the middle of the image src and anything after the image doesn't load , the strange thing that this happens on my pc only , when I try to open the same URL from my mobile or another computer it loads completely

when I change the stored image with smaller one I don't face this problem, again the problem happens only on my pc on chrome, not firefox, (it load completely on firefox)

here is how i retrive the image from database

```
<img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($rowtcategory['image'] ).'" height="100" width="150" class="img-thumnail" />
```

here is the last lines in view page source

```
<img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAZABkAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wAARCAEjAlgDAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAAAAAcBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwAI/8QAVRAAAgEDAgMFBAUHBwsDAwEJAQIDAAQRBSESMUEGEyJRYQcUcYEykaGxwRUjQlJystEIJDM0YqLwFiU2Q
```

then it stops , and this part of view page source appears in red font

I expect the problem in my chrome, but I need to solve because firefox is not working well with my CSS file so I prefer to use chrome
, thanks in advance

Comment: Why you even save images in database? Why not as URL accessible files? Can you provide generated source around this image?

Comment: i store it in database in order to be easier to retrieve as i understood from some developers , what is meant by generated source of image , excuse me because i am not expert in that i am still learning , thanks in advance